# Does the optimal function in kernel method have a sparse representation?

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, machine-learning, sparsity, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

The kernel least square method aims to solve the following problem,

$$f^*=\arg \min_{f\in \mathcal{H}} E_{x,y}[(f(x)-y)^2]+\frac{\lambda}{2}\Vert f\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}$$
, where $\mathcal{H}$ is some pre-specified RKHS with kernel $k(x,x')$, $x\in R^d$ is a feature vector, $y\in R$ is the target value.

In practice, the finite-sample estimator $f_n$ is computed given $n$ i.i.d. samples $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$
$$f_n=\arg \min_{f\in \mathcal{H}}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i)-y_i)^2 +\frac{\lambda}{2}\Vert f\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}$$

I have 3 questions in terms of the estimator $f_n$.

1. is $f_n$ an unbiased estimator, i.e., $E[f_n]=f^*$?
2. is the estimator $f_n$ asymptotically consistent, i.e., $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Vert f_n -f^*\Vert_{\mathcal{H}}=0$
3. By the representer theorem, $f_n=\sum_{i=1}^n w_ik(\cdot, x_i)$ for some $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$. This means $f_n$ can be sparsely represented by finite number of kernels although $\mathcal{H}$ itself is infinite dimensional. Does $f^*$ also have a sparse representation, i.e., $\exists x_1,x_2,\dots,x_M\in R^d,w_1,w_2,\dots,w_M\in R,\text{ such that }f^*=\sum_{i=1}^M w_i k(\cdot, x_i)$? Under what conditions such sparse representation exists or does not exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends what you mean. If you have $M$ observations, then there $f*$ is given (exactly) by the sum you have written.

Comment: The representer theorem works in the case of finite number of observations. But I am very interested in the existence of sparse representation when the number of observations M goes to infinity.

Comment: For the 2-norm a minimization with linear least squares will rarely give anything sparse. But if you iterate and punish small magnitude values in solution harsher and harsher (from differing from 0) the smaller they get then you can get something of the sort.